# Question about Grothendieck's vanishing theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

In the proof of Grothendieck's vanishing theorem, one of the steps says that if $X$ is irreducible of dimension o, then $H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F})=0$ for all $i>0$. This is because functor $\Gamma(X, .)$ induces an equivalence of categories, and $\Gamma(X, .)$ is an exact functor. But this is where my question arises.

Accroding to the definition, functor $H^{i}(X,.)$ is the right derived functor of $\Gamma(X, .)$, and the injective resolution of a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ is an exact sequence. Since $\Gamma(X, .)$ is exact, $H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F})$ is always zero, which is impossible. What do I miss? Thanks!

Comment: Which proof are you referring to?

Comment: The proof in Hartshorne's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Seems like I misunderstood the question. Cohomology doesn't vanish for all $X$ and all $\mathcal F$ simply because $\Gamma(X,\cdot)$ is left exact, but not exact in general.

---

Resolution itself is not exact, it is only exact with augmentation map. What I mean is this: let $0\to \mathcal F\to \mathcal I^\bullet$ be injective resolution of $\mathcal F$. Then the chain complex

$$0\to\mathcal F\to \mathcal I^0\to \mathcal I^1\to\ldots$$

is exact, but you don't apply $\Gamma(X,\cdot)$ to that complex, but to the complex

$$0\to \mathcal I^0\to\mathcal I^1\to \mathcal I^2\to\ldots$$

which has trivial cohomology except at degree $0$: $H^0(\mathcal I^\bullet)\cong \mathcal F.$

So, if $\Gamma(X,\cdot)$ is exact, $H^i(\Gamma(X,\mathcal I^\bullet)) = 0,\ i > 0,$ and $H^0(\Gamma(X,\mathcal I^\bullet))\cong \Gamma(X,\mathcal F)$.

The same reasoning applies to any derived functor: if the original functor is already exact, then all the higher derived functors vanish.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But my confusion is, according to definition, it seems we can conclude that $H^{i}(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}))=0,i>0$ always holds for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on any topological space $X$. This can't be true! I must have lost something in my argument, and I am not sure what it is?

Comment: @Yuyi Zhang, I misunderstood your question then. The answer is that $\Gamma(X,\cdot)$ is not exact in general, but only left exact.

Comment: Ok. But now my second question arises. Why can't a left exact functor guarantee a long exact sequence? It seems to me that in a long exact sequence, we only need to ensure $Img(d_{i-1})=Ker(d_{i})$, and a left exact functor certainly has this property.

Comment: @Yuyi Zhang, I don't understand what you mean. Left exact functor does not preserve short exact sequences, only the left part remains exact (hence the name), i.e. left exact functor won't preserve epimorphisms (otherwise it would be exact). It seems to me this is worth of a separate question :)

Comment: Alright. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Yuyi, maybe to clarify what I mean, left exact functor won't preserve images (since it doesn't preserve cokernels), but it will preserve kernels. So, in general, if you apply left exact functor $F$ to exact sequence, $A\to B\to C$, you get that $\operatorname{ker}(FB\to FC) \cong F(\ker(B\to C)) \cong F(\operatorname{im}(A\to B))\not\cong \operatorname{im}(F(A\to B)).$ Thus, we have nontrivial cohomology in general.

Comment: I am very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

I think I see where the confusion arises. Your statements

"functor $\Gamma(X, \cdot)$ induces an equivalence of categories, and $\Gamma(X, \cdot)$ is an exact functor"

appear to be quoting from Step 2 of the proof (p.210). But look at the first sentence of Step 2:

"Suppose $X$ is irreducible of dimension $0$."

The proof is just saying that *under that assumption*, the global section functor is exact (so higher cohomology of any sheaf on $X$ vanishes, as the theorem claims). But of course exactness is not true for a general $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your point. But is it true that a left exact functor and an exact functor will result the same when acting on an exact sequence?

Comment: No, that is not true.

Comment: I have got my answer, thanks!